# How do I remove horizontal scroll bar from my website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

A horizontal scroll bar appears on my website. It is because of the bootstrap navbar. I tried commenting all the styles in css which targeted the navbar but the scroll bar was still there. How do I reduce the navbar width to fit the screeen. I did try the overflow-x hidden but content got cropped with that.

```css
#main-body{
  margin: 0 70px 0 70px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-color: #14ffec;
  border-width: thin;
}



.navbar-brand{
  font-family: Lilita One;
}

.navbar-top{
  padding: 0 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar{
  padding: 0 5% 0 2%;
}

.brand-icon{
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 990px) {
  .alt-yt{
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 990px) {
  #contact{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f73859;
  }
}

.hor-line {
    width: 40%;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #f73859;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.abhay-pic{
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 30%;
}

.yt-img{
  width: 30px;
}

#footer{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #384259;
  color: #fff;
}

.copy-rt{
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 0.001rem;
}

.social{
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

#contact{
  text-align: center;
}

.contactus{
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.aboutus{
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>College Gyan</title>
  <!-- Tab Icon -->
  <link rel="icon" href="images\CG.ico">
  <!-- Font Awesome For Icons -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3c286cca65.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lilita+One&family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Title Section -->
  <section id="title">
    <!-- Top Navigation Bar -->
    <div class="container-fluid navbar-top">
      <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #384259;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="brand-icon" src="images\CG.png" alt="">College Gyan</a>
        <a class="nav-link ms-auto alt-yt" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnVMMjjk65N5KBZmZn0MmUw"><img class="yt-img" src="images\youtube.png" alt=""></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link ms-auto" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnVMMjjk65N5KBZmZn0MmUw"><img class="yt-img" src="images\youtube.png" alt=""></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Counselling</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Recruitment</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="main-body">
    <p>Education Side</p>
    <p>Education Side</p>
    <p>Education Side</p>
    <p>Education Side</p>
    <p>Education Side</p>
    <p>Education Side</p>
    <p>Education Side</p>
    <p>Education Side</p>
    <p>Education Side</p>
    <p>Education Side</p>
    <p>Education Side</p>
    <p>Education Side</p>
  </section>

  <hr class="hor-line" style="height:2px;">

  <section id="contact">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 aboutus">
        <h5>About Us</h5>
        <p>College Gyan is a technical education start-up offering both business to business to business and business to customer solutions. College Gyan was founded on March 2020, under the aegis of Education Side. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 contact-img">
        <img class="abhay-pic" src="images\Abhay.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 contactus">
        <h5>Contact Us</h5>
        <p><i class="fas fa-phone"></i> 9340356564 <br><i class="far fa-envelope"></i> collegegyanhub@gmail.com</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer id="footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="social" href="https://m.facebook.com/pages/category/Education-Website/College-Gyanhub-109209784094837/"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
      <a class="social" href="https://instagram.com/college_gyan_hub?igshid=15qe861uvoerw"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
      <a class="social" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnVMMjjk65N5KBZmZn0MmUw"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
      <a class="social" href="https://www.linkedin.com/groups/12402330"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
      <p class="copy-rt">© Copyright 2020 College Gyan</p>
    </div>



  </footer>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow-x` to the body.

```
body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```